# Eclipse Project references vs Java EE Module Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

Good Afternoon in my timezone

Can you tell what is the difference between Project References and Java EE Module Dependencies
in Eclipse ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project references set up a dependency for compilation. So if project A references project B, then a class in A will compile successfully if it references a class in B.

Module dependencies (Deployment Assembly in the properties) are for Java EE modules (EARs, WARs, EJB-JARs, RARs). So if a (EAR) project includes another (non EAR) as module dependency, the other project will be included in the *deployment*, as dictated by Java EE specs for the type of the included project.